# python Module management in VsCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Although the PyCharm(a ide for python) is very strong and powerful,unfortunately,i found that it really Occupies Memory and CPU resources.

Then i come up to the VsCode(a lightly text editor),you know,i use anaconda to manage my python package,unfortunately,a weird case happen
[image]

i'am sure that this module is in my `"tmp"` folder,but the interpreter seems not recognize my module.

i guess that there must be some problems in my vs code setting

here is my vs code setting

```
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.enabled": true,
"python.pythonPath": "F:\\Anaconda3\\envs\\tensorflow_cpu\\python.exe"
```

is there any module management in vs code ? 
by the way, even if i enter in the `"tmp"` folder,the interpreter still doesn't work.

Comment: Why would you put your modules in the tmp folder?

Comment: ... and why would it look in `tmp` for modules anyway?  Is it in your `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: i  just wanna know how to add  `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: @Cery export PYTHONPATH="your_path"

Comment: @harpratap emmm,it sounds feasible~  but , there is no reserved word named `export`，do i need import some thing  like `from XXX import export`?

Comment: PYTHONPATH is a system variable. You need to execute this in your terminal if you use Linux or OSX. For Windows you'll need to manually edit it. You can look up how to do it for your particular version of Windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a lot of problems enabling pylint, and after spending 2 days changing all possible settings I switched linter to flake8. Everything just works from the first try, and it's great.
Try enabling flake8 first, then if it doesn't work, you'll have to change your settings and if it does just use it.

If your code can't find your module try this:

1. Create a file named .env in your project root directory
2. Add the following contents to the .env file:

   `PYTHONPATH=path to your module folder`

Comment: after i use `flake8` there is no wrong thrown,but,when i run it in terminal,the same question happen `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'align'`. Oh,this is almost killing me :(

Comment: Do you have a problem with just the linter or your code doesn't run?

Comment: :), i found it really helps me. i add a .env file and it works